# Microsoft teams API or event to get when a user speaks?

Tags: python, ubuntu, microsoft-teams

I am using Ubuntu as my work operating system and Microsoft teams will be working full time in mute mode. So i would i like to know whether there is an API or event through which i can get whether someone speak through teams so that i can automate and reduce my music volume at once.

Or is there any way in linux or python to pick up  when Microsoft teams is using speaker or alsa driver etc.

Comment: It looks like there is no api available for getting whether someone speak through teams. We will confirm it once internally and let you know.

Comment: Could you please go through below document which explains about Active and Dominant speakers
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/real-time-media-concepts#active-and-dominant-speakers

Answer (score 0):

Using Active and Dominant speaker we can identify which meeting participants are currently speaking.

Reference link : [Active and Dominant Speaker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/real-time-media-concepts#active-and-dominant-speakers)

Sample link : [Sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples)